# Tabs Text Color become Black on Selecting the Tab - After clicking anywhere on the screen i get my results

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, bootstrap-4

I am using html,css and bootstrap for designing some tabs.
This is the result  I am getting right now:

[image]

On clicking on anywhere on the screen I get the original results for which i have code.

[The result after clicking on the screen anywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCQ9B.png)

How to solve the 2 problems:

1. On selecting/clicking any tab the Tab Text color will have to change to red. I already tried active keyword as you can see in my code.
2. The actual result can be shown immediately not on clicking on screen.

My code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="tab" role="tabpanel">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#medicalNotes" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Medical Notes</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" ><a href="#medication" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Medications</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#allergies" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Allergies</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#vitalsh" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Vital Social history</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#familyhh" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Family Health history</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content tabs">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="medicalNotes">
                    <h3>Section 1</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce semper, magna a ultricies volutpat, mi eros viverra massa, vitae consequat nisi justo in tortor. Proin accumsan felis ac felis dapibus, non iaculis mi varius.</p>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="medication">
                    <h3>Section 2</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce semper, magna a ultricies volutpat, mi eros viverra massa, vitae consequat nisi justo in tortor. Proin accumsan felis ac felis dapibus, non iaculis mi varius.</p>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="allergies">
                    <h3>Section 3</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce semper, magna a ultricies volutpat, mi eros viverra massa, vitae consequat nisi justo in tortor. Proin accumsan felis ac felis dapibus, non iaculis mi varius.</p>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="vitalsh">
                    <h3>Section 4</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce semper, magna a ultricies volutpat, mi eros viverra massa, vitae consequat nisi justo in tortor. Proin accumsan felis ac felis dapibus, non iaculis mi varius.</p>
                </div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="familyhh">
                    <h3>Section 5</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce semper, magna a ultricies volutpat, mi eros viverra massa, vitae consequat nisi justo in tortor. Proin accumsan felis ac felis dapibus, non iaculis mi varius.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
a:hover,a:focus{
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
.tab .nav-tabs{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dc697f;
    margin: 0;}
.tab .nav-tabs li a{
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0 10px -1px 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: #6da1b7;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 2px solid #e6e5e1;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.tab .nav-tabs li.active a{
    background: #fff;
    color: #6da1b7;
    border: 2px solid #dc697f;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-top-width: 3px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
.tab .nav-tabs li a:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.nav-tabs > li > a{
    color: #D33E1E;
}
.tab .nav-tabs li.active a:before,
.tab .nav-tabs li a:hover:before{ transform: scaleX(1); }
.tab .tab-content{
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #6f6f6f;
    line-height: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    position: relative;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px){
    .tab .nav-tabs{ border: none; }
    .tab .nav-tabs li{
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 15px;

    }
    .tab .nav-tabs li a{
        margin: 0;
        border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    }
    .tab .nav-tabs li a:before{
        content: "";
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        background: #dc697f;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -2px;
        left: 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The color is being getting overided by `nav.less` css file. `!important` is not recommended. Instead you can increase the `specificity` by using different selector and not same as `nav.less`. i:e targeting `a` which has `href` attribute begin with `#`. example - `.tab .nav-tabs li.active a[href^="#"]`.

```css
a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.tab .nav-tabs {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dc697f;
  margin: 0;
}

.tab .nav-tabs li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 10px -1px 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #6da1b7;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px solid #e6e5e1;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.tab .nav-tabs li.active a[href^="#"] {
  background: #fff;
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid #dc697f;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-top-width: 3px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.tab .nav-tabs li a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
  color: #D33E1E;
}

.tab .nav-tabs li.active a:before,
.tab .nav-tabs li a:hover:before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.tab .tab-content {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  line-height: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  position: relative;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .tab .nav-tabs {
    border: none;
  }
  .tab .nav-tabs li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .tab .nav-tabs li a {
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  }
  .tab .nav-tabs li a:before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #dc697f;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="tab" role="tabpanel">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#medicalNotes" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Medical Notes</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#medication" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Medications</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#allergies" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Allergies</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#vitalsh" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Vital Social history</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#familyhh" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Family Health history</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content tabs">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="medicalNotes">
            <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce semper, magna a ultricies volutpat, mi eros viverra massa, vitae consequat nisi justo in tortor. Proin accumsan felis ac felis dapibus, non iaculis mi varius.</p>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="medication">
            <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce semper, magna a ultricies volutpat, mi eros viverra massa, vitae consequat nisi justo in tortor. Proin accumsan felis ac felis dapibus, non iaculis mi varius.</p>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="allergies">
            <h3>Section 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce semper, magna a ultricies volutpat, mi eros viverra massa, vitae consequat nisi justo in tortor. Proin accumsan felis ac felis dapibus, non iaculis mi varius.</p>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="vitalsh">
            <h3>Section 4</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce semper, magna a ultricies volutpat, mi eros viverra massa, vitae consequat nisi justo in tortor. Proin accumsan felis ac felis dapibus, non iaculis mi varius.</p>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="familyhh">
            <h3>Section 5</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce semper, magna a ultricies volutpat, mi eros viverra massa, vitae consequat nisi justo in tortor. Proin accumsan felis ac felis dapibus, non iaculis mi varius.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank You So Much For your Great Effort. 
The problem is still there! 
After doing what you have suggested, The tab text color changes to red when clicked but it turn to black immediately.

Comment: @BilalAsghar - If the answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted in order to indicate the problem has been resolved.